# how to delete and add multiple items without iterating a dictionary in python 3.7x?

Tags: python, dictionary, methods, time-complexity

I wonder if a existing dictionary instance can add and/or delete multiple items without using iterations.
I mean something like this.

supposition:(it actually doesn't work)

```
D = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}
tags = ["key1","key2"]
D.pop(tags)
print(D)
{"key3":"value3"}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `dict` API does not provide methods for adding / removing multiple keys. Python 3.9 offers a way to add multiple items with a single method: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/ but there is no pop for many keys at once yet.

Comment: @kingkupps Can't `dict.update` add multiple items?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to iterate? Because when you want to do something more than once, there pretty much needs to be some iteration *somewhere*, even if it's hidden from you in the implementation of a method (like `update` that can add multiple key, value pairs in a single call).

Comment: @superbrain Ahh whoops yeah you're right. Also agreed with ^. There's just no way to delete many keys in one call

Answer (score 2):

If so, you could iterate a list instead of iterate the full dict:

```
D = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}
for i in ["key1", "key2"]:
    D.pop(i)

print(D)
```

Comment: [D.pop(key) for key in tags]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need to avoid iteration, but rather just want to do the transformation of the dictionary in an expression, rather than a statement, you could use a dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary containing only the keys (and the associated values) that *don't match* your list of things to remove:

```
D = {key: value for key, value in D.items() if key not in tags}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't modify `D` in place, so if you need to change the value referenced through some other variable this won't help you (and you'd need to do an explicit loop). Note that if you don't care about the values being removed, you probably should use `del D[key]` instead of `D.pop(key)`.

Comment: Similar: `{key: D[key] for key in D.keys() - tags}`

Comment: @superbrain That's actually a lot cleverer than my very simple comprehension.

Comment: I want to avoid iteration to reduce time complexity...

Comment: Well, there's definitely going to be *some* iteration, and the complexity of different approaches to it will differ. An explicit loop over `tags` with `del` (or `pop`) will be `O(len(tags))`. My very basic dict comprehension is `O(len(D) * len(tags))` (much worse). The alternative proposed by superb rains is `O(len(D))`.

Answer (score -1):

If all you're wanting to do is show the dictionary where key from list is not present, why not just create a new dic:

```
D = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}
tags=["key1", "key2"]

dict = {key:value for key, value in D.items() if key not in tags}

print(dict)
```